# How can I turn on ggplot2 legend titles?

Tags: r, ggplot2

From what I understand, ggplot2 legend titles should be on by default. However, I can't seem to get mine to appear. I've tried everything I can think (see code), but it's stubbornly missing. I cloned my environment from my boss, so it's possible that it's turned off somewhere (however, my coworkers don't have this problem), but I have no clue where to look in the environment to fix this. I'm also working in RStudio in case this is a quirk there. Any suggestions/fixes are greatly appreciated. :)

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
    sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
    weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)
ggplot(df, aes(x=weight, color=sex)) +
    geom_histogram(fill="white", position="dodge", show.legend=TRUE)+
    theme(legend.position="top") +
    labs(color='NEW LEGEND TITLE') +
    theme(legend.position="top") +
    scale_color_discrete(guide = guide_legend())
```

Produces:
[image: Histogram of fake data with missing legend title]

## Edit

My boss appears to have added a custom theme in the code we source to access his myriad functions, so the solution I've come up with the help of the comments is to add this after sourcing the code:

```
theme_update() + theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12))
```

(Many thanks to the commenters for their useful suggestions!)

Comment: It is weird because if you actually used the code you gave, you should not have this style and background, but the default one of `ggplot` (gray background, white major grid etc). Your ggplot theme is defined somewhere else, and the title disappearing could be related to this hidden theme

Comment: for me your code works fine and also shows the legend title. It looks a bit like the previous behavior when cowplot is loaded (it used to override the default ggplot theme). But also there, for me, the legend title is shown. Maybe try adding `theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold"))`

Comment: try restarting your R session with this code and let us know. you may have changed default ggplot2 theme/settings wondering to make it work like you wanted.

Comment: Yep I get a heading appear too, try using `theme_get()` to see what your boss has set as the default theme in the envir. Maybe `theme_get()$legend.title` is set to `element_blank`?

Comment: @TobiO, you've solved it! Thank you!
Vincent Bonhomme, I see them in a vanilla R session, but we have to source the intricate set of R scripts my boss has written over the last decade-plus so I can't practically always graph in a vanilla session.
user2738526, I get list() - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "element_blank" "element". I guess that means it's both blank and has an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force printing of the legend title, specify its properties:

```
plot+
theme(legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=12, face="bold"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing duplicate code (e.g. theme(legend.position=”top”) and erase scale_color_discrete which should be redundant. I think the last piece might cause trouble although it may not be the case.

On a side note, try mapping sex to the fill aesthetic and use alpha = 0.5 in geom_histogram and play around with it if you are unfamiliar with this feature.

Comment: Does this answer the question, or are these juist general hints? If so, make this answer a comment at best.

Comment: Skotten89 probably also wanted to comment but couldn't do that because of the low reputation point